# Once I implement redux, do I use it for every prop I have?

Tags: redux, react-redux

What's the company standard? If a company decides to adopt Redux, do I need to convert every state/prop into redux form?

For example. I have a loading/setLoading state for the home page. Can't see if being used in other places. Do I need to make a redux version of actions for it?

Answer (score 1):

No, as stated in the [Redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/) (general reading recommendation!), you should [Evaluate Where Each Piece of State Should Live](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#evaluate-where-each-piece-of-state-should-live).

Not everything needs (or even should) be global data. Only use Redux for stuff that is "global". **It does not replace props or local component state!**